# Do I need a bridging header to import Google AdMob SDK version 7.0+ podfile into my Xcode Project?

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, cocoapods, bridging-header

I have a small completed Xcode project written in Swift 2.0. I am displaying Google AdMob banners and interstitials.

Previously, I manually imported the GoogleMobileAdsFramework to facilitate the banners and interstitials. But I would like to use CocoaPods to allow for automatic updates to the GoogleMobileAdsFramework moving forwards.

I followed the instructions at Google AdMob's developer section and have setup a podfile in my working Xcode project to incorporate automatic updates to the Google AdMob SDK.

I set up my podfile as follows:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
```

... installed the podfile ... and everything seems to be in order.

I re-opened my working project by clicking on MyProjectName.xcworkspace and get two dependancies - my project and the pods.

Do I need to create a bridging header in my project to import the relevant framework headers from the podfile created? Or does it happen automatically?

I remember reading somewhere that you no longer need a bringing header to import framework headers from the GoogleMobileAds Framework. Is this also the case when I use the podfile approach?

Should I delete the GoogleMobileAdsFramework library from my project dependancy as I already have it in the podfile section of my overall project?

Comment: Nope you dont, you can just import your library using -> import libraryName

Comment: @SanjanPiya So I should delete the 'old' GoogleMobileAdsFramework library I imported before and simply replace it with the library in the 'new' Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks directory?

Comment: Yeah you should certainly delete the old library that you imported manually. Also remove the import statement from your bridging header.

Comment: @SanjanPiya Terima kasih!